# Chart.js — drawing an arbitrary vertical line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I draw an vertical line at a particular point on the x-axis using Chart.js?

In particular, I want to draw a line to indicate the current day on a LineChart. Here's a mockup of the chart:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQDWR.png

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Update** - this answer is for Chart.js 1.x, if you are looking for a 2.x answer check the comments and other answers.

You extend the line chart and include logic for drawing the line in the draw function.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <canvas id="LineWithLine" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("LineWithLine").getContext("2d");

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineWithLine",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var point = this.datasets[0].points[this.options.lineAtIndex]
        var scale = this.scale

        // draw line
        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.moveTo(point.x, scale.startPoint + 24);
        this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
        this.chart.ctx.lineTo(point.x, scale.endPoint);
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();

        // write TODAY
        this.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        this.chart.ctx.fillText("TODAY", point.x, scale.startPoint + 12);
    }
});

new Chart(ctx).LineWithLine(data, {
    datasetFill : false,
    lineAtIndex: 2
});
```

The option property lineAtIndex controls which point to draw the line at.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dbyze2ga/14/

Comment: Thank you @potatopeelings, that's exactly what I was looking for. I don't have enough rep to upvote you but obviously would if I could.

Comment: No worries at all. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Neat and simple :)

Comment: This is great but I what I want it to draw a bar from index1 to index 2. Any way to do this?

Comment: A bar, or you want to shade the address under 2 points in a different color?

Comment: @Sheetal - Didn't quite get that. You might want to post an image of what you are looking for. Cheers! Also, the new version of Chart.js (v2.1.x) is now released. The above answer is for v1.x

Comment: This is a nice solution. Can you update this for chart js version 2.1.6?

Comment: I was trying to replicate this using the plugin service (Chart.pluginService.register), but it's not working properly, Anyone have any ideia on how to adapt that?

Comment: Would love to know if there is a way to draw the line BEHIND the chart?  In otherwords, before the chart is rendered

Comment: @ArunSS [Solution for Chart.js 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329630/chart-js-2-0-vertical-lines)

Comment: How about this but only appear on hover of an x-axis line?

Answer (score 73):

Sharing my solution for chartjs.org version 2.5. I wanted to use a plugin, to make the implementation reusable.

```js
const verticalLinePlugin = {
  getLinePosition: function (chart, pointIndex) {
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0); // first dataset is used to discover X coordinate of a point
      const data = meta.data;
      return data[pointIndex]._model.x;
  },
  renderVerticalLine: function (chartInstance, pointIndex) {
      const lineLeftOffset = this.getLinePosition(chartInstance, pointIndex);
      const scale = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'];
      const context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

      // render vertical line
      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      context.moveTo(lineLeftOffset, scale.top);
      context.lineTo(lineLeftOffset, scale.bottom);
      context.stroke();

      // write label
      context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
      context.textAlign = 'center';
      context.fillText('MY TEXT', lineLeftOffset, (scale.bottom - scale.top) / 2 + scale.top);
  },

  afterDatasetsDraw: function (chart, easing) {
      if (chart.config.lineAtIndex) {
          chart.config.lineAtIndex.forEach(pointIndex => this.renderVerticalLine(chart, pointIndex));
      }
  }
  };

  Chart.plugins.register(verticalLinePlugin);
```

Usage is simple then:

```
 new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: data,
     label: 'Progress',
     options: options,
     lineAtIndex: [2,4,8],
 })
```

The code above inserts red vertical lines at positions 2,4 and 8, running through points of first dataset at those positions.

Comment: This is awesome and highly reusable! Great solution! +1

Comment: Reviving this old post, but is it possible to configure different text for each vertical line?

Comment: Sure, you just have to adapt it slightly. Instead of lineAtIndex array you should provide a map with index=>text, iterate over it in the afterDatasetsDraw method and use the text from the map in the renderVerticalLine method where 'MY TEXT' is currently rendered.

Comment: Chart.js may have some bug now that is causing a ReferenceError "Chart is not defined"

Comment: While I upvoted this solution, it does have a limitation that is pretty ugly, in that it is not possible to add lines at values that lie between indices. But it turned out to be a great tutorial.

Comment: I changed the input a bit, so I can change the color and text.
`[{ x: 10, text: "Sample test", color: "#ff0000" }]` And changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Changing "afterDatasetsDraw" to "beforeDatasetsDraw" draws the vertical line behind the chart instead of on top of! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I'd highly recommend to use the [Chartjs-Plugin-Annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).

An example can be found at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZywgKr)

```
var chartData = {
  labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    }
  ]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            type: "line",
            mode: "vertical",
            scaleID: "x-axis-0",
            value: "MAR",
            borderColor: "red",
            label: {
              content: "TODAY",
              enabled: true,
              position: "top"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Have a look here for more Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431041

Comment: It works for me - without any further information, i wont be able to help you

Comment: I am trying to add this in Ionic project mobile. Did you created this for web ?

Comment: Yes, i created it for a website. maybe you should created a seperate question with more information to your actual problem and provide some source code.

Comment: Resolved Thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655173/chart-js-v2-draw-horizontal-baraverage-over-vertical-bar/47752998#47752998

Comment: All chart.js plugins are messy. That can explain why they are «plugins» and not included in the core. This follow a lot of testings. Chart.js is okay, but don't use plugins, guys, make yours.

Answer (score 7):

I had to go through the trouble of figuring out how to do something similar with ChartJS 2.0 so I thought I would share.

This is based on the new way of overriding a chart prototype as explained here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2321

```html
var ctx = document.getElementById('income-chart');

var originalDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw = function (ease) {
    originalDraw.call(this, ease);

    var point = dataValues[vm.incomeCentile];
    var scale = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'];

    // calculate the portion of the axis and multiply by total axis width
    var left = (point.x / scale.end * (scale.right - scale.left));
                
    // draw line
    this.chart.chart.ctx.beginPath();
    this.chart.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    this.chart.chart.ctx.moveTo(scale.left + left, 0);
    this.chart.chart.ctx.lineTo(scale.left + left, 1000000);
    this.chart.chart.ctx.stroke();

    // write label
    this.chart.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    this.chart.chart.ctx.fillText('YOU', scale.left + left, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 7):

With chart.js **3.8.0** I've used a combo between line/bar chart with timeline (xAxis) and percentage (yAxis). See [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/combo-bar-line.html)

The dataset configuration provides a option to set the `maxBarThickness` (I've applied 2) and then apply the max value of the y-axis on each data entry of the bar chart.

Example of dataset configuration:

```
datasets: [
  {
    type: 'line'
    data: [
      {x: "2022-07-18", y: 10},
      {x: "2022-07-19", y: 60},
      {x: "2022-07-20", y: 30}
    ],
    ....
  },
  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [
      {x: "2022-07-19", y: 100}
    ],
    maxBarThickness: 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

Example of the output:

[image]

Comment: If the chart already got another bar chart, this is still possible with [stacked bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) (and dataset order if necessary)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a pen that achieves a similar effect without the chartjs-plugin-annotation, or hacking how Chart.js renders, or any other plugins: https://codepen.io/gkemmey/pen/qBWZbYM

### Approach

1. Use a combo bar / line chart, and use the bar chart to draw the vertical lines.
2. Use two y-axes: one for the bar chart (which we don't display), and one for all your other line chart datasets.
3. Force the bar chart y-axes to `min: 0` and `max: 1`. Anytime you want to draw a vertical line, add a data object like `{ x: where_the_line_goes, y: 1 }` to your bar chart dataset.
4. The pen also adds some custom data to the bar chart dataset and a legend filter and label callback to exclude the bar chart dataset from the legend, and control the label on the vertical line.

### Pros

1. No other dependencies. No custom monkey patching / extending.
2. The annotations plugin doesn't seem to be actively maintained. For instance, atm, their event handlers throw an error about "preventing default on passive events"
3. Maybe a pro: The annotations plugin always shows the labels of lines drawn, and you have to use their event callbacks to get a show-on-hover effect. Chart.js tooltips show on hover by default.

### Cons

1. We're adding custom data in the dataset config, and hoping it doesn't conflict with anything Chart.js is doing. It's data Chart.js doesn't expect to be there, but as of 2.8, also doesn't break it.

Comment: this approach would be perfect if we can find a way to apply a linear axis for bar chart, add redundant data to display the chart is not really what I can expect

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced version of @Tomáš Dvořák answer

[image]

Supports:

- custom text for labels
- custom color for line+label
- custom alignment for labels
- custom X/Y offset for labels

```
    const verticalLinePlugin = {
      getLinePosition: function (chart, pointIndex) {
          const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0); // first dataset is used to discover X coordinate of a point
          const data = meta.data;
          return data[pointIndex]._model.x;
      },
      renderVerticalLine: function (chartInstance, pointIndex, label, color, alignment, xOffset, yOffset) {
          const lineLeftOffset = this.getLinePosition(chartInstance, pointIndex);
          const scale = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'];
          const context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
          if (xOffset == undefined) xOffset = 0;
          if (yOffset == undefined) yOffset = 0;

          // render vertical line
          context.beginPath();
          context.strokeStyle = color;
          context.moveTo(lineLeftOffset, scale.top);
          context.lineTo(lineLeftOffset, scale.bottom);
          context.stroke();

          // write label
          context.fillStyle = color;
          context.textAlign = alignment;
          context.fillText(label, lineLeftOffset + xOffset, (scale.bottom - scale.top) / 2 + scale.top + yOffset);
      },

      afterDatasetsDraw: function (chart, easing) {
          if (chart.config.lineAtIndex) {
                labelIndex = 0;
                chart.config.lineAtIndex.forEach((pointIndex) => {
                    if (chart.config.verticalLinesLabels != undefined) { // if array of labels exists...
                        label = chart.config.verticalLinesLabels[labelIndex]; // chart.config.verticalLinesLabels must contain all elements; use  elements ="" for lines not requiring labels
                        color = chart.config.verticalLinesColors[labelIndex]; // chart.config.verticalLinesColors must contain all elements
                        alignment =  chart.config.verticalLinesAlignments[labelIndex]; // chart.config.verticalLinesAlignments must contain all elements
                        xOff =  chart.config.verticalLinesX[labelIndex]; // chart.config.verticalLinesX must contain all elements
                        yOff =  chart.config.verticalLinesY[labelIndex]; // chart.config.verticalLinesY must contain all elements
                    } else {
                        label = "";
                    }
                    this.renderVerticalLine(chart, pointIndex, label, color, alignment, xOff, yOff)
                    labelIndex++;
              });
          }
      }
      };

      Chart.plugins.register(verticalLinePlugin);
```

Usage:

```
myChart.config.verticalLinesLabels = ["aaa", "bbb", "ddd"]; 
myChart.config.verticalLinesColors = ["#FF0000", 'rgb(0,255,0)', 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)']; 
myChart.config.verticalLinesAlignments = ["left", "center", "right"]; // Set label aligment (note: it is inverted because referred to line, not to label)
myChart.config.verticalLinesX = [10,5,0]; // Set label X offset
myChart.config.verticalLinesY = [10,5,0]; // Set label Y offset
myChart.config.lineAtIndex = [10,30,50]; // Mandatory to enable all previous ones
myChart.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript version of the vertical line plugin by [Tomáš Dvořák](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824515/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k) for chart.js 2.9.4 and above:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js'
import {ChartOptions} from 'chart.js'

export interface ChartVerticalLine {
  pointIndex: number
  label: string
  color: string
  nPoints: number
}

export const verticalLinePlugin = {
  id: 'verticalLines',
  getLinePosition: function(chart: Chart, pointIndex: number) {
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0) // first dataset is used to discover X coordinate of a point
    const data = meta.data
    const returnVal = data[pointIndex]._model.x
    return returnVal
  },
  renderVerticalLine: function(chartInstance: Chart, pointIndex: number, text: string, color: string, nPoints: number) {
    const lineLeftOffset = this.getLinePosition(chartInstance, pointIndex)
    const area = chartInstance.chartArea
    const context = chartInstance.ctx
    // render vertical line
    if (context !== null) {
      context.beginPath()
      context.strokeStyle = color || '#ff0000'
      context.moveTo(lineLeftOffset, area ? .top)
      context.lineTo(lineLeftOffset, area ? .bottom)
      context.stroke()
      // write label
      context.fillStyle = color || '#ff0000'
      const leftQuartile = 0.25 * nPoints
      const rightQuartile = 0.75 * nPoints
      context.textAlign = pointIndex < leftQuartile ? 'left' : pointIndex > rightQuartile ? 'right' : 'center'
      const offsetText = pointIndex < leftQuartile ? `    ${text}` : pointIndex > rightQuartile ? `${text}    ` : `  ${text}  `
      context.fillText(offsetText || '', lineLeftOffset, area.top + 6)
    }
  },
  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart: Chart, args: any, options: any) {
    if (options.lines) {
      options.lines.forEach((line: ChartVerticalLine) =>
        this.renderVerticalLine(chart, line.pointIndex, line.label, line.color, line.nPoints)
      )
    }
  },
}
```

Then register the plugin:

```js
  Chart.plugins.register(verticalLinePlugin)
```

To use the plugin, just include it as one of the plugin attributes set in the chart options:

```js
    const options: ChartOptions = {
      ...otherChartOptions, 
      plugins: {
        verticalLines: {
          lines: [
            {
              pointIndex: 100,
              label: 'First Line',
              color: '#ff0000',
              nPoints: 1000
            },
            {
              pointIndex: 200,
              label: 'Second Line',
              color: '#ff0000',
              nPoints: 1000
            },
            {
              pointIndex: 300,
              label: 'Third Line',
              color: '#ff0000',
              nPoints: 1000
            },
          ],
        },
      }
    }
```