# Chart.js - draw horizontal line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to draw a horizontal line in a chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). But I'm not able to do it.

I've read this question - [Chart.js — drawing an arbitrary vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line?rq=1) - but I can't transform the code for drawing **horizontal lines** not vertical.

I hope you can help me (especially potatopeelings :)).

Comment: How is it that all these answers suck? They have the wrong version or are horrifically documented. Can't believe that it's so complex

Comment: Here you are going to find code and JS fiddle for
[Chartjs2+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206852/5119682)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the JavaScript code to draw a horizontal line.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("LineWithLine").getContext("2d");

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineWithLine",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var point = this.datasets[0].points[this.options.lineAtIndex]
        var scale = this.scale
        console.log(this);

        // draw line
        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.moveTo(scale.startPoint+12, point.y);
        this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
        this.chart.ctx.lineTo(this.chart.width, point.y);
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();

        // write TODAY
        this.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        this.chart.ctx.fillText("TODAY", scale.startPoint + 35, point.y+10);
    }
});

new Chart(ctx).LineWithLine(data, {
    datasetFill : false,
    lineAtIndex: 2
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7a4hhzge/455/

This is based off of [the code used to draw an arbitrary vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line?rq=1), it may not be perfect but you should be able to adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Everything works. But do you know how to change the code to set value, where the line should be displayed, not only points?

Answer (score 16):

Without any additional code, I managed to draw a line by adding a new entry as a dataset with these options :

Just replace  with the size of your dataset, and  with the value that the line represents.

```
{
  data: Array.apply(null, new Array(<length>)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, <value>),
  fill: false,
  radius: 0,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
}
```

The radius of 0 will somehow hide the dots and the fill: false will make it appear as a line.

Comment: I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object` when I use your `Array.Apply` method

Answer (score 5):

If you need many lines with certain Y value, try this code

```
var data = {
    labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("LineWithLine").getContext("2d");

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineWithLine",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var lines = this.options.limitLines;

        for (var i = lines.length; --i >= 0;) {

            var xStart = Math.round(this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft);
            var linePositionY = this.scale.calculateY(lines[i].value);

            this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = lines[i].color ? lines[i].color : this.scale.textColor;
            this.chart.ctx.font = this.scale.font;
            this.chart.ctx.textAlign = "left";
            this.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "top";

            if (this.scale.showLabels && lines[i].label) {
                this.chart.ctx.fillText(lines[i].label, xStart + 5, linePositionY);
            }

            this.chart.ctx.lineWidth = this.scale.gridLineWidth;
            this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = lines[i].color ? lines[i].color : this.scale.gridLineColor;

            if (this.scale.showHorizontalLines) {
                this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
                this.chart.ctx.moveTo(xStart, linePositionY);
                this.chart.ctx.lineTo(this.scale.width, linePositionY);
                this.chart.ctx.stroke();
                this.chart.ctx.closePath();
            }

            this.chart.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = this.lineColor;
            this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
            this.chart.ctx.moveTo(xStart - 5, linePositionY);
            this.chart.ctx.lineTo(xStart, linePositionY);
            this.chart.ctx.stroke();
            this.chart.ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
});

new Chart(ctx).LineWithLine(data, {
    datasetFill : false,
    limitLines: [
        {
            label: 'max',
            value: 17,
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .8)'
        },
        {
            label: 'min',
            value: 1
        },
        {
            value: 7,
            color: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, .8)'
        }
    ],
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vsh6tcfd/3/

Answer (score 3):

Based on dFelinger message I made a new char type that draws an average line on the line chart. Here's the code, just copy and call a new chart with the new type called 'lineWithAverage' WORKS ONLY FOR CHARTJS 2

```
    Chart.controllers.lineWithAverage = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            Chart.controllers.line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        draw: function () {
            Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

            var scale = this.scale
            var sum = 0;
            this.getDataset().data.forEach(function(value) {
              sum = sum + value;
            });

            var average = sum / this.getDataset().data.length;

            var averageCoord = this.calculatePointY(average);

            // draw line
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx = this.chart.chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx.beginPath();
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx.moveTo(0, averageCoord);
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = '#979797';
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx.lineTo(this.chart.chart.width, averageCoord);
            this.chart.chart.canvas.ctx.stroke();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I've found to create a horizontal line was by just creating a new dataset with every entry set to some constant value (y = 75 for example). Then I set `pointRadius` and `pointHitRadius` to zero to hide the tooltips and points on the graph.

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: your_data,
    ...
  },
  {
    data: your_data.map(r => 75),
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHitRadius: 0,
  },
]
```