# How to draw Horizontal line on Bar Chart Chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have the following script of drawing bar chart and I wanna add horizontal line on particular y dot. I was trying following example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705062/chart-js-draw-horizontal-line-based-on-a-certain-y-value) and I just substituted  `Chart.types.Line.extend` with `Chart.types.Bar.extend`
but as a result I'm getting `can not read property extend of undefined`
So can someone help to implement above example which in the link properly or suggest another decision

*my source code without horizontal line*

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        },


                    }]
                },

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) to do that. Plugins let you handle specific events such as `beforeUpdate` or `afterDraw` and are also easy to implement :

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart) {
        // Code here will be triggered ... after the drawing
    }
});
```

An easy way to do it is to simply draw a line like you would you on a simple canvas element, after everything is drawn in your chart, using the [**`lineTo`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) method.

---

Here  is a small example (*[and its related code](https://jsfiddle.net/h5nzaejr/)*) of how it would look like :

[image]

Comment: You mention something about maths... Try using `var position = yAxe.getPixelForValue(lineAt)` - and maybe checking if it is within bounds...

Comment: hey @tektiv 
thanks for the suggestion. The only thing to improve - you can use `chart.canvas.getContext("2d")` inside the plugin to avoid the context hard-coding and thus getting a working module.

Answer (score -1):

With the answer from @tektiv, your `yAxis` always starts at `0`.

This is a working example without the use of `yAxe.min`, so
you can use it (for example, with `beginAtZero:false`) and the `yAxe` scales automatically with your data.

Line plugin:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("barCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart) {
        if (typeof chart.config.options.lineAt != 'undefined') {
            var lineAt = chart.config.options.lineAt;
            var ctxPlugin = chart.chart.ctx;
            var xAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].id];
            var yAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].id];
            ctxPlugin.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctxPlugin.beginPath();
            lineAt = yAxe.getPixelForValue(lineAt);
            ctxPlugin.moveTo(xAxe.left, lineAt);
            ctxPlugin.lineTo(xAxe.right, lineAt);
            ctxPlugin.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

Chart:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
       lineAt: 14,
       scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }
            }]
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer uses yAxe.min in its jsFiddle. You can use this code  for example with ` beginAtZero:false ` so the yAxe scales automatically to your data. With the Answer from @tektiv your yAxis always starts with 0.