# ChartJS - how to display line chart with single element as a line? (not as a dot)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-mixed-chart-types + AngularJS wrapper: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

> When creating a chart, you have the option to overlay different chart types on top of each other as separate datasets.
>
> To do this, you must set a type for each dataset individually. You can create mixed chart types with bar and line chart types.
>
> When creating the chart you must set the overall type as bar.

There is a slight difference how lines are presented - if I display `bar` and `line` on the same graph, the line does not go to an end.

[image]

It doesn't really matter that much, unless I have single element only...
[image]

ChartJS displays line charts with single element as a dot - [Chartjs linechart with only one point - how to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225719/chartjs-linechart-with-only-one-point-how-to-center) *(and they suggest added some `null` elements, I'm not sure if I want to follow that route)*

Here some example how to draw vertical line on canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/zk9oc4c9/ *(feels like too much effort calculating everything manually)*

### Codepen: http://codepen.io/stefek99/pen/WpRQgp?editors=1010

**Maybe there is a better way?**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705062/chart-js-draw-horizontal-line-based-on-a-certain-y-value ? `not yet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This helped me a lot: [How to draw Horizontal line on Bar Chart Chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293816/how-to-draw-horizontal-line-on-bar-chart-chartjs/39346235#39346235)

Here is the working demo: http://codepen.io/stefek99/pen/ZeXzBr?editors=1010

### Defining a plugin:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart) {

        if (typeof chart.config.options.lineAt != 'undefined') {
            var lineAt = chart.config.options.lineAt;
            var ctxPlugin = chart.chart.ctx;
            var xAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].id];
            var yAxe = chart.scales[chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].id];

            var position = yAxe.getPixelForValue(lineAt)

            ctxPlugin.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctxPlugin.beginPath();
            ctxPlugin.moveTo(xAxe.left, position);
            ctxPlugin.lineTo(xAxe.right, position);
            ctxPlugin.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

### Checking if the line is required

```
var _drawLineOnTopOfADot = function(chartData) {
  if (chartData.labels.length !== 1) return; // only handling graphs that have single item
  if (chartData.dataSetOverride.length < 2) return; // only when we have at least two types of graph
  var indexOfLineGraph = -1;
  for (var i=0; i<chartData.dataSetOverride.length; i++) {
    if (chartData.dataSetOverride[i].type === "line") {
      indexOfLineGraph = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (indexOfLineGraph === -1) return; // no line chart, no worries

  chartData.options = chartData.options || {};
  chartData.options.lineAt = chartData.data[indexOfLineGraph][0]; 
}
```

I've spent way too much time on that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the options that you found, you could use the [chart.js annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) to easily draw your line without having to mess with rendering pixels in your canvas manually.  Note, the plugin is created/supported by the same team as chart.js and is mentioned in the [chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#notes-popular-plugins).

Here is an [example codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/qrXxGE) demonstrating your scenario.

Once you add the plugin, you simply just set additional properties in your chart config.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [5]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Stacked Bar and Unstacked Line Combo Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          enabled: false,
          content: 'Test label'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

This is still a little cumbersome because you have you define the location of the line separate from your data point value, but its certainly easier then the other approach.

I'm not sure if there is an existing angular extension of the plugin, but I assume you can create one easy enough if need be.

Comment: Thank you for helping! At the end of the day I used a different approach with `afterDraw` plugin...

Comment: How did you do this @MichalStefanow ? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Date of the comment is the same as the accepted answer (to the minute). I'll suggest you check the accepted answer.