# Extending Existing Chart Types angular chart js using chart js 2.0

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using the great [chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) 
 (Version: 2.0.2) and [angular-chart.js](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) (Version: 1.0.0-beta1) for compatibility purposes. There are a lot of functionalities I would like to add to my project (like [adding a horizontal line to a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839760/angular-chart-add-horizontal-line) or having a [rounded corners bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582555/how-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-chart-js-bar-chart)). All theses solutions use

```
Chart.types.[typeOftheChartToExtend].extend({..}).
```

I'm stuck using it with chart.js v2.0, the [doc](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-extending-existing-chart-types) isn't very clear. How can I extend existing chart **using chart.js v2.0** ?

Any advice or example would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I too have same problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer but you can extend the shape of the element, not the type of the specific chart, from v2.

For example,

```
Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
   // Do your draw thingy.
}
```

There's [an issue regarding this one at the official Github repo](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3072) and also [a great example of implementing it](http://codepen.io/jedtrow/full/ygRYgo/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the line chart:

```
var originalLineController = Chart.controllers.line;
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function() { 
        originalLineController.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
        /* own drawing code here */
    }
}
```

You can get the context with:

```
var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
```