# Chart.js 2.1.6: Drawing horizontal Limit Lines?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need to draw horizontal limit lines for my line and my combined (bar and line) charts. There was a solution for Chart.js < 2.0 like shown here:

[draw horizontal line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092489/chart-js-draw-horizontal-line)

but this solution is no longer working with chart.js > 2.0:

```
jquery.1.12.1.js:9743 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

So how am i supposed to draw limit lines in Chart.js 2.1.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [Chart.Annotation.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.Annotation.js) to your project and do:

```
annotation: {
    annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: '25',
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
}
```

in the `options`

Answer (score 0):

You can draw horizontal and vertical line in chart.js ,
Try this , ywhich is using Chart.js `Version: 2.2.1`

[http://plnkr.co/edit/8HJtZ7WKmTEy2gGuOT0v?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HJtZ7WKmTEy2gGuOT0v?p=preview,)

thanks to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8x6fso/) ,I Updated it with latest version of chart.js and do changes on that.

Comment: With your solution: How would it be possible to let the horizontal line start at a defined y-Value? And how would it be possible to create multiple limit lines? Because that is exactly the purpose of a limit line in charts.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in drawing multiple limit lines (e.g. one limit for each data point), I found an easy approach was to simply create a mixed chart, with a line-series representing your limit points. Once you have this, you can use the following options to turn the line points into flat lines, and hide the overall line:

`pointStyle: 'line',
radius: 20,
fill: false,
showLine: false,`