# Add horizontal Line to my chart.js Barchart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

Hi I want to add a horizontal line to my Barchart. This is the Code of my chart:

```
var singleBarOptions = {
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    barShowStroke: true,
    barStrokeWidth: 1,
    barValueSpacing: 5,
    barDatasetSpacing: 1,
    responsive: true
};

var singleBarData = {
    labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],

    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,191,255,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(0,191,255,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(100,149,237,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(100,149,237,1)",
            data: [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20]
        }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("singleBarOptions").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(singleBarData, singleBarOptions);
```

Is there an easy way to draw this line?
It would also be nice if I could change the position of the line later on.

There are solutions here on stackoverflow, but they don't deal with settings.

Comment: Can you please put this in a fiddle and share the link?,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart.js - draw horizontal line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092489/chart-js-draw-horizontal-line)

Comment: its not a duplicate, they only have a dataset. I don't know how to add my settings to their code.

Comment: please create fiddle of the code u tried

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the Annotations plugin:[Chart.Annotation.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.Annotation.js)

```
annotation: {
    annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: '26',
        borderColor: 'tomato',
        borderWidth: 1
    }],
    drawTime: "afterDraw" // (default)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Codepen: [Chart.js Annotations BarChart](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/yaGGGW?editors=0010)

Note: I am using V 2.2.1, your syntax is I believe from a previous version, so I am only using your Data and some options.