# Chartjs line graph with ranges

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

So I need to create a CUSUM control chart and would like to use ChartJS (https://www.chartjs.org/) to do so (example here: https://www.spcforexcel.com/knowledge/variable-control-charts/keeping-process-target-cusum-charts). Basically this chart has a standard line graph but with an upper target (control limit) and a lower target marked to show when the line has moved outside the desired range.

Is this possible with ChartJS and if so how? I have looked at the examples and I'm not seeing how to do it.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31092938/2358409

Comment: That is super - thank you. If that is the complete answer I'll remove my question!