# Chart.js - Creating Custom Chart Types

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create a Linegraph that renders 3 **different** datasets separately of each other. The y-axis is shared.

For instance, the first 4 points belong to dataset 1 (green), the next 7 points belong to dataset 2 (yellow), and the last 9 points belong to dataset 3 (red). The lines in each dataset do *not* connect. I'd also like to draw a vertical line in-between each graph on the shared canvas to distinguish the datasets further.

Having 3 canvas elements for each line graph is not cutting it for me. The Chart.JS docs are not clear on how to go about this type of customization. Any help to get me on the right track to code this myself is desired.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can't help you with Charts.js but I can recommend you Highcharts. take a look at this. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Comment: How is your use case different from the basic Line Chart (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart) example of Line.js? There is a good example how to display multiple to Line Graphs on one Canvas. You will just need to split your points into three seperate lists by the sound of it.

Comment: show us code what you have tried so far, so we can help you on that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend the chart to draw lines (see [Chart.js — drawing an arbitrary vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line)) and use null values to hide line segments, like so

---

**Preview**

### [image]

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var scale = this.scale

        // draw lines
        this.chart.ctx.save();
        this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';

        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.moveTo(scale.calculateX(1.5), scale.startPoint);
        this.chart.ctx.lineTo(scale.calculateX(1.5), scale.endPoint);
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();

        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.moveTo(scale.calculateX(6.5), scale.startPoint);
        this.chart.ctx.lineTo(scale.calculateX(6.5), scale.endPoint);
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();

        this.chart.ctx.restore();
    }
});

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [28, 48, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [null, null, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, null, null]
        },
        {
            label: "My Third dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,205,187,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,205,187,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,205,187,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,205,187,1)",
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 24, 32]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/buhuebdm/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed but I had hoped to be given direction not answers.

Comment: Hi, how can I set min value and max value for Yaxis in your sample code?

Comment: @VAAA Just use the chart options `scaleSteps`, `scaleStepWidth` and `scaleStartValue` (from  https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.1/docs/00-Getting-Started.md)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the multiple data sets (except to agree with the comments that it should work) but regarding your request "*I'd also like to draw a vertical line in-between each graph on the shared canvas to distinguish the datasets further.*" I wrote some rough code to draw lines over the top of my graphs that might be a useful starting point for you.  I'm extending the Bar chart where you'll want to extend the Line chart but that should be a simple text replacement in the code below.

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: 'BarOverlay',
    draw: function (ease) {

        // First draw the main chart
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

        var barWidth = this.scale.calculateBarWidth(this.datasets.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.verticalOverlayAtBar.length; ++i) {

            var overlayBar = this.options.verticalOverlayAtBar[i];

            // I'm hard-coding this to only work with the first dataset, and using a Y value that I know is maximum
            var x = this.scale.calculateBarX(this.datasets.length, 0, overlayBar);
            var y = this.scale.calculateY(2000);

            var bar_base = this.scale.endPoint

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)';
            ctx.moveTo(x, bar_base);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.closePath();
    }
});
```

This also needs a change to the options structure to store a list of overlay coordinates:

```
// Add an array of columns at which a vertical line should be drawn
verticalOverlayAtBar: []
```

Note that my bars are vertical rather than horizontal.

To use this I set up the chart as usual but call my overlay method instead of the base chart:

```
var ctx = $("#PdCallHistoryChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var PdHistoryChart = new Chart(ctx).BarOverlay(PdChartData, HistoryChartDefaults);
```

The overlay logic draws the main chart and is then free to work with the canvas and has access to the properties of the underlying graph so can calculate offsets based on the data drawn.

This is fairly rough so any Chart.js experts can feel free to wade in with criticism.