# Chart.JS Vertical Line with Moment.JS Horizontal Axis

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is there a way to create vertical lines (event lines, phase changes) using Chart.JS 2.0?

I've seen some examples online ([see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line)), HOWEVER, when using Moment.js to create the horizontal axis, it is not possible to give LineAtIndex a moment.js date to create a line at that date.

```
    var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    if (index) {
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/harblz/0am8vehg/

I believe my issue is that I don't properly understand this bit of code:

var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
  var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

If I am able to figure this out, I'll post a working fiddle here for any future users tackling the same project.

Thanks you for your time reading this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried multiple plugins, but none could handle Charts with cartesian axes of type *time*. My rather simple solution:

First register the **chart plugin** globally:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  drawLine: function (chart, xValue, color = 'rgba(87,86,86,0.2)') {
    const canvas = chart.chart
    const context = canvas.ctx

    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(xValue, 6) // top
    context.lineTo(xValue, canvas.height - 73) // bottom
    context.strokeStyle = color
    context.stroke()
  },

  afterDraw: function (chart) {
    const xScale = chart.scales['x-axis-0']

    if (chart.options.verticalLine) {
      chart.options.verticalLine.forEach((line) => {
        const xValue = xScale.getPixelForValue(line)

        if (xValue) {
          this.drawLine(chart, xValue)
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Then add **verticalLine** Array to your chart definition:

```
options: {
   scales: { xAxes: [{ type: 'time' }] },
   verticalLine: ['2019-04-1', '2019-07-01', '2019-10-01'],
 }
```