# Chart JS, How to draw a vertical line between points

Tags: chart.js

How to draw a vertical line between points in graph using chart js. I tried with provided URL option [Chart.js — drawing an arbitrary vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line) but it draws full top to bottom line. One more thing is vertical line right now shows us on hover but i need vertical line with onload of graph not the hover.