# Chartjs angular Horizontal bar chart with line

Tags: angular, chart.js, bar-chart, horizontal-line

i'm using chartjs with angular. I have an horizontal bar chart and I want to display some data of type 'line' above the bars. It works, if the bar chart is not horizontal.

[something like this, but horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2sum.png)

Is that possible using chartjs? If so, how?

Comment: Hi. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: No i don't found any solution.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line I hope this helps