# Chart JS Crosshair - Linked Charts without linked Legends

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have an application using Chart JS and the great extension [chartjs-plugin-crosshair](https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair) to provide zoom and a vertical line on hover. It's ability to 'link' charts is critical as it highlights values on separate charts across the same x-axis.

The issue is the linked charts also have linked legends. I've created a simple example: https://codepen.io/sheixt/pen/JjGvbVJ

Here is an extract of the Chart `option` config (see the link for the full script):

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    crosshair: {
      sync: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: "interpolate",
    intersect: false,
    callbacks: {
      title: function (a, d) {
        return a[0].xLabel.toFixed(2);
      },
      label: function (i, d) {
        return d.datasets[i.datasetIndex].label + ": " + i.yLabel.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see, if you "turn off" a dataset (e.g. Dataset 1, **A** in *chart 1*, **D** in *chart 2*, and **G** in *chart 3*), the dataset is removed from all of the linked charts.

I have a series of charts that are based on the same x-axis data so the crosshair line & the tooltip appearing on all of the linked charts is ideal. But as each dataset that is plotted is not the same across the various charts, I do not want it to disappear on click.

So in my example deselecting Dataset 1 on *chart 1* **A** would be removed but **D** in *chart 2*, and **G** in *chart 3* should remain.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the chart and write your own type with horizontal and vertical arbitrary lines as it is shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line).

Here is an update if you need it for version 2

HTML

```
<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

SCRIPT

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

Chart.defaults.crosshair = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.crosshair = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function (params) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, params);
        
        if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
                var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                 ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                 x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                 y = activePoint.tooltipPosition().y,
                 topY    = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].top,
                 bottomY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom,
                 startX  = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].left,
                 endX    = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].right;

               // draw line
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
                ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
                ctx.moveTo(startX, y);
                ctx.lineTo(endX, y);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(55, 55, 55)';
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }
    }
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'crosshair',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255,0)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

Result
[image]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

Chart.defaults.crosshair = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.crosshair = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function (params) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, params);
        
        if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
                var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                 ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                 x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                 y = activePoint.tooltipPosition().y,
                 topY    = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].top,
                 bottomY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom,
                 startX  = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].left,
                 endX    = this.chart.scales['x-axis-0'].right;

               // draw line
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
                ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
                ctx.moveTo(startX, y);
                ctx.lineTo(endX, y);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(55, 55, 55)';
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }
    }
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'crosshair',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255,0)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```