# Add an feature DateOfTheDay in my Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I looked for a lot of things to add a feature to my chart but
I couldn't find it in the documentation or here,
I would like to add a visual addition of today's date, on the bottom legend for example,
does anyone have any examples or ideas? thank you in advance
[image: Example of my chart with the feature]

```js
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [ <?php echo $txt_labels; ?> ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Réelle',
            yAxisID: 'A',
            data: [ <?php echo $txt_series1; ?> ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(238, 121, 83, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(238, 121, 83, 1)",
            pointRadius: 5,            
        }, {
            label: 'Attendue',
            yAxisID: 'B',
            data: [ <?php echo $txt_series2; ?> ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(167, 172, 200, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(167, 172, 200, 1)",
            pointRadius: 5,  
        }]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {
        animateScale: true,
        animateRotate: true,
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'easeInOutSine',        
       },
        scales: {
          x:{
            grid: {
            borderColor: 'rgba(16, 16, 18, 0.5)',
            offset: true,       
            },
          },
            A: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
                grid: {
                  display: false,
                  borderColor: 'rgba(16, 16, 18, 0.5)',
                },
                ticks: {
                  font: {
                    size: 14,
                  },
                  callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
                  }
                }, 
            },
            B: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',                                             
                  }
                },               
            },
        },       
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js — drawing an arbitrary vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line)

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use annotation plugin https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Comment: I tested version 3 and it doesn't correspond to my data or else I can't understand how to integrate it...
in the example, the visualization of the line is something static, so I would have to correspond to today's date